# xCode4 stagnates for a blink of an eye during scrolling

Tags: iphone, xcode

since I have xCode4 it crashed on me already several times - it seems in particular during updates on textView contents using copy/paste.

Now it started to pause or stagnate during scrolling. I move the two fingers down once, twice and only then or even after the third time it suddenly starts and skips all the pages too fast. Also, once in a while it stops for a character or two during typing....

I don't have anything else runnig on the MacBookPro - so xCode shouldn't really have trouble. Also no app is running... Maybe its doing garbage collection in the background since it seems to happen more often when I pause and then continue rather than during editing ????

Do you have similar issues or any idea where its could come from? Thanks!

Comment: Have you filed a bug report on this: https://bugreport.apple.com/ ?  The only way this will be improved is to let the engineers know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any external peripherals plugged in? This is common for me when Time Machine kicks in and starts backing up 50+ GB of data. Could also just be hiccups in Xcode 4. They still haven't ironed all the bugs out.

Comment: I tried this in the meanwhile, but it does not help. Some of my class files are about 2-3k lines, maybe that's too much. I will try several combinations and report back...

Comment: @user387184: That could be it. Perhaps Xcode4 isn't polished enough yet to handle multiple multi-thousand line files.

Comment: In the meanwhile I checked the CPU usage and the HD activity during scrolling. The CPU goes quite high but is still OK. The problem is with the HD activity, there is a red peak everytime scrolling blocks. Red means written bytes in the activity analysis. So now that I know that, is there anything I can do?